# How to get values from nested array/ dictionary iOS 7

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, dictionary

I fetch values from dictionary and need to display in UITableView, but everything works fine.

On some spot it stops running and shows thread

```
-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbfa7670
```

The code below, which I used to fetch value..

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[pageCat1 valueForKeyPath:@"img3"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
```

My values are fetched properly in dictionary but lags to display it?

```
pageCat (
    {
    img3 = "http://xxx.in/images/page_cat_img/75x75/4.jpg";
    name = "PVC Flexible Wires";
    page =         (
                    {
            id =                 {
                text = 1;
            };
            img4 = "http://xxxx.in/images/page_img/75x75/1.jpg";
            name = "SINGLE CORE FLEXIBLE WIRES ABOVE 6 SQMM";
        },
                    {
            id =                 {
                text = 72;
            };
            img4 = "http://xxx.in/images/page_img/75x75/72.jpg";
            name = "SINGLE CORE FLEXIBLE WIRES BELOW 6 SQMM";
        }
    );
},
    {
    img3 = "http://xxx.in/images/page_cat_img/75x75/3.jpg";
    name = "Bare Copper Wires";
    page =         {
        id =             {
            text = 29;
        };
        img4 = "http://xxx.in/images/page_img/75x75/29.jpg";
        name = "Tinned Copper Fuse Wires";
    };
},
    {
    img3 = "http://xxx.in/images/page_cat_img/75x75/48.jpg";
    name = "Properties of Wire";
    page =         {
        id =             {
            text = 85;
        };
        img4 = "http://xxx.in/images/page_img/75x75/85.jpg";
        name = "Wires - Normal, HR - PVC, FR, FRLS & Zero Halogen";
    };
}
```

)

Actually look at the log value, it has array and set of values.. i can't find whether it is in what form..

Can anyone help me to find the solution??

Thanks,
Yazh

Comment: what  is the actually response can you please show us that you are trying to get value.

Comment: In tableview, on clicking a cell displays its sub category..
Thread SIGART is show on my code which i mention above.

Comment: sir i said actual  output of responce pageCat1

Comment: pageCat {
    img3 = "http://xxxx.in/images/page_cat_img/75x75/38.jpg";
    name = Chennai;
    page =     {
        id =         {
            text = 129;
        };
        img4 = "http://xxxx.in/images/page_img/75x75/129.jpg";
        name = "Consultants In Chennai";
    };
}

while log pagecat it shows array like this.. Am Miss not sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
//Assuming json is your main dictionary    

NSDictionary *pageCat = [json objectForKey:@"pageCat"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[pageCat valueForKey:@"img3"]mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Value=%@", [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

Comment: Can you post here the NSDictionary value please. NSLog(@"pageCat1=%@",pageCat1);

Comment: Please check is it working:   NSDictionary *pageCat = [json objectForKey:@"pageCat"];
        NSMutableArray *array = [[pageCat valueForKey:@"img3"]mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"Value=%@", [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

Comment: Okay convert it into NSMutableArray form. Try with this one:  NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[pageCat valueForKey:@"img3"]; and after that first print array and if it works fine then try with objectAtIndex.

Comment: yes. Juz look at the log values, it is in different format. so only i can't access values. Can anyone tell me how to fetch it..

Comment: can you write here, what it prints  NSLog(@"array=%@",array);

Comment: i already displayed it in my question.. juz go through it. I find alternate sol, bt it replicates same data..

Comment: Not that one. I am asking for the array which I told you above. Try with this one: NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[pageCat valueForKey:@"img3"]; and after that first print array. Give me the output of this array.

Comment: array Office Lighting
 array Retail Lighting
 array Hospital Lighting

this is printed as log value..

Comment: Now you have an array with values. You can easily access values from its index.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like `[pageCat1 valueForKeyPath:@"img3"]` returns a `NSString` and not a `NSArray` like you expect

make sure that it returns a `NSArray` before applying `objectAtIndex`:

it seems that `pageCat1` is a NSArray so you need to write something like:

```
NSString *path = pageCat1[0][@"img3"];

...
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error already tells, `[pageCat1 valueForKeyPath:@"img3"]` returns a `NSString` and you are calling `objectAtIndex:` on it which is not recognized for this class. Obviously, `pageCat1` differs from what you expected.

Try `NSLog(@"%@", pageCat1);` to see what it really looks like.

**// Edit**

`pageCat1` (as seen in your update) is an `NSArray` that contains items of type `NSDictionary`. What you really want to do is `NSString *imgURL = [[pageCat1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"img3"];`

Explanation: 
1. `[pageCat1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` returns a `NSDictionary`
2. `[__dictionary__ objectForKey:@"img3"]` returns the NSString containing your image URL

Answer (score 1):

Actually I used XML data, for that i used third party to parse data. Its all of third party which parsed alternate data as array and other as non-array. Finally I check the array with

```
isKindOfClass
```

and convert it into array. Therefore my problem in app solved. :-)

Thanks to all who help me..